# Scene is not loading properly from asset Bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

Three days ago I am stick with **asset bundle with unity 4.x** what I have tried so far is given below:

**Making Scene Asset bundle**s using this code snippet which successfully making .unity3d Scene asset bundles for me

```
public class SceneAssetBundleMaker : EditorWindow {

    bool groupEnabled;

    public static string sceneName;
    static string sceneNameWithPath;
    static string sceneNameWithPathAssetBundel;
    [MenuItem("AB Scene/BuildSceneAsset")]


    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(SceneAssetBundleMaker));

    }

    void OnInspectorUpdate()
    {
        Repaint();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical("Box");
        GUILayout.Label("Enter Scene Name");
        sceneName = EditorGUILayout.TextField(sceneName);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Make Asset Bundle"))
        {
            if (sceneName != null)
                myBuild();
            else
                Debug.LogError("sceneName must be entered");
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

    }
     static  void myBuild()
    {
        //        string[] levels = { "Assets/Scene/SimpleBakingPlanAndBoxes.unity" };
        //string[] levels = { "Assets/Scene/"+ sceneName+ ".unity" };
        sceneNameWithPath = "Assets/_project/_scenes/" + sceneName + ".unity";
        Debug.Log("sceneNameWithPath" + sceneNameWithPath);
        string[] levels = { sceneNameWithPath };
        Debug.Log("levels : " + levels.Length);
        Debug.Log("levels 0 : " + levels[0]);

        sceneNameWithPathAssetBundel = "Assets/AssetBundles/" +sceneName + ".unity3d";
        string v = BuildPipeline.BuildStreamedSceneAssetBundle(levels, sceneNameWithPathAssetBundel, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
        Debug.Log(v);
        //"Streamed-Level1.unity3d"
        //BuildPipeline.BuildStreamedSceneAssetBundle(levels, "Streamed-Level1.unity3d", BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows64);

    }   
}
```

while this code is using to download scene Asset bundle

```
public IEnumerator LoadSceneBundle(string assetBundleSceneName, string orignialName) {
        url = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/" + assetBundleSceneName + ".unity3d";
        Debug.Log("scene load url : " + url);
        using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(url,1)){
            yield return www;
            if (www.error != null) {
                throw new Exception("WWW donwload had an error : " + url + " " + www.error);
                //Debug.Log("");
            }
            AssetBundle ab = www.assetBundle;
            Debug.Log("Main Asset :: " + www.assetBundle.mainAsset);
            ab.LoadAll();
            Application.LoadLevel(orignialName);
            ab.Unload(false);
        }
    }
```

**Two scene** I am switching both are from asset bundles by this code. The code working in fine but not always. Some times it loads the scene and some times it is not while the same situation i am facing in build standalone.

After deployment I have made a folder of AssetsBundel and placed my assetbudel scene files in it but all is in vain.